# Return next position in a 2d array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

Let's say we have a 2D array:

```
arr =
[
 ['A',  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
 ['B',  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
 ['C', 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
 ['D', 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
]
```

Therefore if I have a for loop iterating through the array:

```
for (row = arr.length - 1; row >= 0; row--)
{
 for (column = arr[0].length - 1; column >= 0; column--)
 {
  if (arr[row][column] == 5)
  {
   return arr[row + 1][0]
  }
 }
}
```

I want the returned value to be 'B', however the increment of the array return the error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined

And my limited grasp of javascript (GAS) is frustrating my attempts to find a solution to this.

Thanks!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I'd like to return the element in the next "row" and first "column". Therefore if element = 5, arr[0][6], then 'B' needs to be returned.`. In your showing array, it seems that `arr[0][6]` is undefined. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: For example, `arr = [arr.flat()]` is your expected script? In this case, `arr` is `[["A",1,2,3,4,5,"B",6,7,8,9,10,"C",11,12,13,14,15,"D",16,17,18,19,20]]`. And, `arr[0][6]` is "B". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion in my initial question, I've edited it to attempt to make my problem more clear.  The value could be *any* of the numbers but the returned value always needs to be the letter in the same sub-array.

Comment: In your `for` loops you are starting with the highest row and column and counting backwards.  Shouldn't your limit be `row >= 0` and `column >= 0`.  In fact your loops aren't doing anything and the error may be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted and the discussion has already been advanced. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer and discussions.

Answer (score 1):

Logical error where array not pulling data from datasheet. Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
function myFunction() {

  var arr = [['A', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ['B', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], ['C', 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], ['D', 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]];

  for (let row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {

    for (let col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++) {

      if (arr[row][col] == 5) {

        console.log(arr[row + 1][0]);
        break; 

      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Execution logs:**

[image]

Comment: "@Century Tuna" , thanks for this but while this works returning to the log, the logic fails  when returning to google sheet.

Comment: @Drew254 just to further clarify on this, the sample array you have above came from a Google Sheet, and you would like to set the value on a specific cell within your Google Sheets is that correct?